# How can I change a plots function after a certain time period coding in Python using Pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to plot basically two functions Positions respect to time.

The first function is
U = 2.67t
The second function is
J = 2t+4

When plotted the functions intersect at time, t = 6. (x-axis) and position 16. (y-axis)
What im trying to do is that after the two lines intersect the function U, should equal function J.
The current results im having look like this:
[Current Plot Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMY9i.png)
you can see that the line for UAV continues after t=6, however I want it to change and equal to function J after t=6.

I hope you understand. Here is my full code currently:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0,int(20/1))

#Jackal
def xj(t):
    return (2*t+4)

#UAV
def xu(t):
    return (2.67*t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.plot(xu(t),label='UAV Path')
    plt.plot(xj(t),label='Jackal Path')
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('Position')
    plt.title('Pose Vs\nTime Graph')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Use two different `t` vectors. It should only contain the relevant values for `xu` and `xj`

Answer (score 0):

I think a quick and dirty way would be to incorporate an if statement into your function and decide which of the two functions to return based on t.

Another way would be to enter the ranges 0-6 and 6-20 into the corresponding plot functions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions and ideas. I figured it out.

```
import numpy as np
import time;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t = np.arange(0,int(20/1))
u = 6 

#Jackal
def xj(t):
    return (2*t+4)

#UAV
def xu(t):
    y = []
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i] >= u:
            y.append(2*t[i]+4)
        else:   
            y.append(2.67*t[i])
    return y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plt.plot(xj(t),label='Jackal Path')
    plt.plot(xu(t),label='UAV Path')
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel('x(t)')
    plt.ylabel('y(t)')
    plt.title('Pose Vs\nTime Graph')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```